# How angular2 is going to use shadow dom while it's not supported in some popular browsers?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, angular

From the [documentations](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/annotations/ComponentAnnotation-class.html):

> When a component is instantiated, Angular
>
> ```
> creates a shadow DOM for the component.
> loads the selected template into the shadow DOM.
> creates a child Injector which is configured with the appInjector for the Component.
> ```

But, as far as I know, shadow DOM is not supported yet in **IE**, **Safari**, and even in default configuration of **Firefox**!

Considering the fact that shadow DOM is not a feature that can be easily added to browser via a js library or something, how will be browser support for angular2?

PS: forgive me for calling IE and Safari (specifically IE) ***popular browsers!***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular 2 has two modes for Shadow DOM: emulated & native. In other words, browsers without Shadow DOM support will get an effective but slower polyfill.

[Discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/526) & [Source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2/src/render/dom/shadow_dom)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know any detail about the `EmulatedShadowDomStrategy` but I still kinda feel that shadow DOM is not a feature that can be added or "emulated" without browser support!

Comment: [Polymer](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) would be a good example of a library that polyfills Shadow DOM in all modern browsers. Essentially, the polyfill looks like this: 


`(function() {
    if ('createShadowRoot' in HTMLElement.prototype) { return; }
    HTMLElement.prototype.createShadowRoot = function() {
        return this.shadowRoot = this;
    };
})();`

Answer (score 0):

Both Angular 2 and Polymer use Polyfills to emulate the Shadow DOM. Polymer calls it [Shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html).

*Note that these polyfills are supported only in the latest versions of the Browsers, like IE 11.*